# Error: You can add up to 5 000 Products to a Category

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, b2b, e-commerce, categories

In Salesforce B2B eCommerce, when I try to add many of my products to a Product Category I recieve this error: "*You can add up to 5 000 Products to a Category. Delete some Products and try again*"
Does anybody know how to bypass this limitation ?  I have product categories with more than 5000 products inside...

Answer (score 1):

I have been informed that Salesforce can increase the limit by opening a case with them.